# Query to return all values in a specific table column

Tags: sql, t-sql

The query below returns a somatory of all groups in the year.

How can I return all groups that exists in `IND_GRUPO` but grouped by the month, if doesn't exist the group for the current month, the name should appear, but the somatory will be 0. All joins should be kept.

```
SELECT SUM(p.valor), c.nm_grupo, c.cd_grupo, YEAR(p.dt_emissao)
FROM ind_receita p
JOIN ind_equipto o ON p.cd_equipto = o.cd_equipto
JOIN ind_grupo c ON o.cd_grupo = c.cd_grupo
WHERE YEAR(p.dt_emissao) = YEAR(GETDATE())
GROUP BY YEAR(p.dt_emissao), c.nm_grupo, c.cd_grupo
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT c.nm_grupo, c.cd_grupo, YEAR(GETDATE()),
    (SELECT SUM(p.valor)
    FROM ind_receita p
    JOIN ind_equipto o ON p.cd_equipto = o.cd_equipto
    JOIN ind_grupo c2 ON o.cd_grupo = c2.cd_grupo
    WHERE c2.cd_grupo = c.cd_grupo
    AND YEAR(p.dt_emissao) = YEAR(GETDATE())) AS valor
FROM ind_grupo c
```

Comment: Works fine, I was trying get the result using CTE, but your approach was far better

Comment: @Lucas_Santos: Ok, have a nice day ;)